# How do you read math operations with parenthesis?

Tags: mathematics

I don't know how to read math operations with (){}[] in English.

```
2(3x^2+1)-6
```

If you read this, do you say

1. "two parenthesis three x squared plus one minus six"
2. "two parenthesis three x squared plus one closed minus six"

or are there any other ways to say that? If you read 1, does it confuse `2(3x^2+1)-6` with `2(3x^2+1-6)`?

Comment: I personally would speak that expression "two times the sum three x squared plus one, minus six" but there is a lot of variation in rendering mathematical expressions into spoken English. The question linked by @Heartspring has a pretty good reply even though the question there has itself been closed.

Comment: (Incidentally, I just read my example rendering to a friend, and she wrote down your operation exactly from my words.)

Comment: In my experience people often use *brackets* to include *parentheses*, and may or may not distinguish verbally between *round brackets* and *square brackets*.

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach would be:

> two *open parenthesis* three x squared plus one *close parenthesis* minus six

In computing, "parenthesis" is quite often shortened to "paren" (see [Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/paren)).

This is quite awkward, of course, which is why long equations are rarely read out loud.

Comment: I would personally use *open parentheses* and *close parentheses* (the plurals), referring to the pair of parentheses being opened or closed. If I was being fussy enough to read symbol by symbol (and therefore use the singular) I would not interpret "^2" as *squared*. Really just personal preference though.

Answer (score 1):

To sort this out, I would listen to an accessible-technology screen reader reading [MathML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathML), as demonstrated in this video: [NVDA and Firefox Reading MathML on Wikipedia](https://youtu.be/0TCpqL0QuWc).

tl;dl: *open paren* / *close paren*